# 4gb twinmos 1600mhz RAM not working

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

I am using ECS G41T-m16 motherboard which have bus speed of FSB 1333 mhz. I have been using 2gb ddr3 apacer ram 300mhz for last 2 years.Recently, I have bought a 4gb twinmos 1600mhz RAM but it is not working only 2gb RAM is gotten by my ubuntu 14.04 64bit . I change the RAM slots of both RAM still it is not working.

If I remove the 2gb RAM, The pc with only 4 gb RAM is restarting again and again.

What can I do now ?

Comment: You been using 300mhz you sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like compatibility issue with your RAM and Motherboard. If possible please try with different RAM with 4 GB 1600mhz and check the results.

> If the other RAM works fine then its issue with your 4 GB RAM
>   Else if the other RAM too face the same issue, then you have to contact ECS  Support with the details to arrive at a right solution.

This will help to isolate the problem and arrive at a solution.